# CreateJavaVM Failed

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat9

I have installed one of the old project using Java 11.0.2. When I tried starting tomcat 9 as a service I am getting below errors.

```
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [info]  [13044] Starting service... 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [error] [ 9764] CreateJavaVM Failed 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [error] [ 9764] The system cannot find the file 
specified. 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [error] [13044] Failed to start Java 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [error] [13044] ServiceStart returned 4 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [info]  [13152] Run service finished. 
[2019-05-03 05:01:36] [info]  [13152] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

I verified jvm.dll path. Its correct.  Below are the command used to start tomcat service

```
C:\Java11\bin\tomcat9.exe //IS//TOMCATSERVER --StartClass 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams 
stop
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance, 
AKJ.